The Selenium drag-and-drop action places an element in a different location when executed in CodeBuild compared to running it locally
I am actionchains to perform drag and drop function of a particular source to middle of particular target.
But when I ran the script in my local elements are placed at example 1,2,3,4 order.
But when I ran the script in codebuild it is placing element in 1,3,2,4 order.
So, I thought the issue is because of window size and add window size arguments for chromeoptions.
Already tried window size: [1920,1080],[1280,593],[800,500]
Nothing worked and also used these in headless chrome.
